# SharePoint list - Validation settings Formula

Tags: list, calculated-column, validation, settings

I have a SharePoint 2010 list with Drop Down column named "A" which has 3 choice values.

The list has 3 more columns namely "B","C" and "D".

I'm trying to set a validation on the list as below:

- When choice 1 is selected in Column "A",columns "B","C" and "D" can be blank.
- When choice 2 is selected in Column "A",column "B" should be made mandatory.
- When choice 3 is selected in Column "A",columns "C" and "D" should be made mandatory.

I'm not able to make my formula work for more than 1 choice.Below is the formula I have:

```
=IF([A]="Choice 1",IF(OR([B],[C],[D]="",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it fits to your use case but you could think about using different content types instead of your column A and for each content type you could define your columns B, C and D to be mandatory or optional

Comment: Is J query an option we could consider?

Comment: @mohd tahir yes i can consider jquery also.can u help me with the jquery?

Comment: @George Please check the answer I have given below.

Answer (score 2):

The below Validation formula worked for me:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([B])=TRUE,[A]="Choice 2"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([C])=TRUE,[A]="Choice 3"),FALSE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([D])=TRUE,[A]="Choice 3"),FALSE,TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add a Script editor webpart to your 'New Item' Page.
2. Add refrences for JQuery and Sptility on the top.
3. Add below code on your page:

**Heres your code**:

```
<script language="javascript" src="../SiteAssets/Jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../SiteAssets/sputility.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

function PreSaveAction() {
var fieldA = SPUtility.GetSPField('A').GetValue();
var fieldB = SPUtility.GetSPField('B').GetValue();
var fieldC = SPUtility.GetSPField('C').GetValue();
var fieldD = SPUtility.GetSPField('D').GetValue();
if(fieldA=='Choice #1')
{
return true;
}
else if(fieldA=='Choice #2')
{
if(fieldB=='')
{
alert('Please enter value in column B');
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
else if(fieldA=='Choice #3')
{
if(fieldC=='' || fieldD=='')
{
if(fieldC==''&& fieldD=='')
{
alert('Please enter values in column C and D');
return false;
}
else if(fieldC=='')
{
alert('Please enter value in column C');
return false;
}
else if(fieldD=='')
{
alert('Please enter value in column D');
return false;
}
}
else
{
return true;
}
}

}
</script>
```

If you need more help let me know please. If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as answered.